# Neo4J not Showing Selected Edges

Tags: neo4j

I have imported some data into Neo4j that looks like this:

```
API1,API2,Dist,Relation,Side,Bench
3302502244,3302503497.0,981.0,Sibling,R,below
3302502244,3302503240.0,664.0,Sibling,L,same
3302502244,3302502246.0,321.0,Sibling,L,above
3302502246,3302502642.0,681.0,Sibling,L,same
```

Using this code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nearness_edges.csv" AS row
MERGE (t:Well {API: toInteger(row.API1)})
MERGE (f:Well {API: toInteger(row.API2)}) 
MERGE (t)<-[:Relation {Distance: toFloat(row.Dist), ParSib: row.Relation}]-(f)
MERGE (t)<-[:Direction {Distance: toFloat(row.Dist), LftRgt: row.Side}]-(f)
MERGE (t)<-[:Bench {Distance: toFloat(row.Dist), AboSamBel: row.Bench}]-(f)
MERGE (t)<-[:near {Distance: toFloat(row.Dist), ParSib: row.Relation, LftRgt: row.Side, AboSamBel: row.Bench}]-(f)
```

Now when I query the database to show all Sibling relationships with `match (t:Well)<-[r:Relation {ParSib: 'Sibling'}]-(f:Well) return t,r,f` the browser shows me all the nodes *but not the edges* (see first screenshot below). Note that the query is returning the edges correctly, just not showing them (see second screenshot below) I need to have the "Connect result nodes" option off because otherwise, the browser shows *all* edges, and not just the ones I have selected in the query.

Why can't I draw just the nodes + the edges I want?

[image: Vis'd query results]
[image: Query results]

Comment: Note it's just a visualization, the text view will paint a clearer picture of what the result actually looks like.
Is the graph visualization better with `match (t:Well)<-[r:Relation {Relation: 'Sibling'}]-(f:Well) return t,r,f` (note I got rid of the WHERE clause because it's an exact match)

Comment: In both my query and yours, the result is returning both the expected nodes and edges, so there's nothing wrong in the query. The visualization, however, is really what I need here. I need Neo4j to display the specified nodes & edges.

Comment: My query returns all pairs of well connected via a sibling relation, and I expect the graph view to display these given they are explicitly returned with the query. Can you share a screenshot, highlighting what's missing or extra?

Comment: I've added screenshots to the post. Note that I also renamed edge attributes, on the off chance that there was a collision between edge type and attribute (no change in behavior).

Comment: It seems it's because "Connect result nodes" is off, although I'd have expected the browser to display the results anyway :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded the sample data you gave and it works well. The issue you have is probably due to a setting in Neo4j Desktop.  Go to Settings (left bottom; icon looks like a gear) then double check the settings on Graph Visualization.

Example: Below will only display two nodes without an edge.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I increased all those parameters, and the graph displayed as expected.